# HTML & CSS: How I can make an image's bottom edge align with text?

Tags: html, css, alignment

In my HTML pages I have text with `img`s. The **top** edge of the `img` is aligned with the top of the text, but I want the **bottom** of the `img` to be aligned with the text.

How can this be done?

**UPDATE** Now I see this is the default behaviour, but it doesn't happen in my page. What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: Could you post an example?  My first instinct is that you're inheriting an unwanted style silently, but it's hard to say without code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I came back to add line breaks and decided to throw an example in, too.

You can do this with CSS's vertical-align property.  Something like this:

```
<img src="wherever.png" style="vertical-align: text-top;" />
```

More information about the style is available at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), where they have a neat [sandbox](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align).